# Regular expression to find if all letters in a set or range exist anywhere in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a regular expression in JavaScript to find if each of the letters in 'abt' is available anywhere in the string.

```
 console.log(/(?=.*a)(?=.*t)(?=.*b)/i.test("at good and bad"));
```

If I have more characters to identify I have to make this regular expression long.
Can any one suggest me how can I optimize this?

If I have to match a specific range like a-z what I should do?

Comment: does the order matter? `bta` ?

Comment: no order doesn't matter

Comment: `[/a/, /b/, /c/].every(chr => chr.test(input))`?

Comment: if i have to match a range like a-f .what i should do?

Comment: @AmitKumarShrivastava, the suggestion by *torazaburo* is quite good for your case, if  each of characters should  be presented

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i don't think it is optimized because if i have a-z then i have to write too long .

Comment: Are you searching any specific word or character?

Comment: Then just write `chrRange('a', 'f').every(chr => input.includes(chr))`. You'll have to write `chrRange` yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I think the following should work:

```
(.?[a]{1,}.?)|(.?[b]{1,}.?)|(.?[t]{1,}.?)
```

This will match any string that contains any of those letters at any position, in any word within the string.  if you have to do ranges, like say, a-c, change the [a] to [a-c] and that will still work.  This is case sensitive so if you want to check in a manner that is not case sensitive it would be[a-cA-C] or [aA].

Tested working at regex101.com